# showing <h:panelGrid> when a commandButton is clicked.. both are in the same form

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a list of input fields followed by a command button. After I click a command button a `<p:panelGrid>` has to be loaded below the command button. Both are in the same form. Initialy panel grid is disabled.

```
input fields:
<h:inputText/>
<h:inputText/>
<h:outputLabel/>
<h:commandbutton value="view"/>
panelGrid:
<p:panelGrid> 
<p:row>
<p:column>  col1  </p:column>
<p:column>  col2  </p:column>
<p:column>  col3  </p:column>
</p:row>
<p:row>
<p:column>  col11  </p:column>
<p:column>  col22  </p:column>
<p:column>  col33 </p:column>
</p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) First you forgot the form

2) It's commandButton tag, not commandbutton

```
    <h:form id="form">

input fields:
    <h:inputText/>
    <h:inputText/>
    <h:outputLabel/>
    <h:commandButton value="view"/>
    panelGrid:
    <p:panelGrid> 
    <p:row>
    <p:column>  col1  </p:column>
    <p:column>  col2  </p:column>
    <p:column>  col3  </p:column>
    </p:row>
    <p:row>
    <p:column>  col11  </p:column>
    <p:column>  col22  </p:column>
    <p:column>  col33 </p:column>
    </p:row>
    </p:panelGrid>

</h:form>
```